# Drupal failed after update

Tags: 7, updating

I just updated Drupal core from 7.4 to 7.26. After running update.php site stopped working – both public and admin part. When I load it fatal error occurs:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _system_default_theme_features() in /[drupal_path]/includes/theme.inc on line 1422

and when I reload it another fatal error apperars:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDirectoryPath() on a non-object in /[drupal_path]/modules/image/image.module on line 83

next reload – first error, one more – second. Also, second error is loading much faster.

And one more thing, after applaying update.php I got one failed, I don't know if this is connected:

> media_gallery module
>
> Update #7009
>
> Failed: FieldException: Próba aktualizacji egzemplarza nieistniejącego pola media_gallery_media. w field_update_instance() (linia 557 z /[drupal_path]/modules/field/field.crud.inc).

which is something like:

> Failed: FieldException: Attempt to update an instance of a nonexistent field media_gallery_media. in field_update_instance() (line 557 in /[drupal_path]/modules/field/field.crud.inc).

PHP Version 5.5.6

I was trying disabling some modules from db (especially image.module, media_gallery already was disabled), but this did't help.

Any tips where the problem is? Thx in advance.

Comment: Po pierwsze, spróbuj odpalić stronę po angielsku jeśli się da. Najciekawszy komunikat wkleiłeś w języku, którego większość osób tutaj nie zrozumie. Second thing, if media_gallery already was disabled, then of course upgrade failed to update fields that belongs to it. It is unwise to disable modules without purging their data before upgrades.

Comment: heh, racja. I'm not very wise ;) I've tried to update.php after enabling this module in db, but error still occurs. And I don't know if it is connected with main problem – fatal errors on main page..

Comment: [`_system_default_theme_features()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/_system_default_theme_features/7) is defined at line 2655 of modules/system/system.module - if it cannot be found, something went very, very wrong.

Comment: yes, it's there. and it's defined exactly the same.

Comment: looks like we have a winner. Is it possible that something turned off system.module, and did not turn it on? uhmm...

Comment: Possible... hard, but possible

Comment: If you have drush then look into Registry Rebuild.